# Cannot disable Javascript Debugging in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am building an ASP.NET Web Forms application (not site) and whenever I debug with Internet Explorer, I cannot seem to disable the integrated Javascript debugging with Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

How do I get it to stop breaking on Javascript exceptions?

*My OS is Windows 2012 Server R2 (so, equivalent to Windows 8.1 Pro) with IE11. I have tried every setting that I could find but nothing has worked so far. I have even logged out and back in. I am going to try a complete reboot right now.*

The screenshots below show all the settings I've tried.

#### Exception and Settings:

[image: Exception Occurrence and Settings]

---

#### Visual Studio Options - Debugging:

[image: Visual Studio Debugging Options]

---

#### Internet Explorer Options:

[image: Internet Explorer Options]

---

#### BrowserLink Disabled

[image: BrowserLink Options]

---

Comment: I have same issue. My error lies within JQuery library and is due to crappy old HTML/Javascript. Very frustrating that you turn off all debugging but that windows pops up.. every.. single... page refresh.

Comment: I think the final answer is: Use Chrome or Firefox if you don't want VS to debug IE automatically when you run your project. If you run your web project with IE, VS will automatically attach to the IE process and debug it and there is no way to disable that.

Comment: If you need to test on IE, you can make VS run with Chrome or FF and then while that's running, just start IE and go the web project address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run your web project with IE, VS will automatically attach to the IE process and debug it and there is no way to disable that.

So, start debugging with Chrome or Firefox if you don't want VS to debug IE automatically when you run your project. Then open up IE and navigate to your site if you still need to test with IE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no user-unhandled column on yours Exceptions window, if its hide make it appear and uncheck all check marks. See:
[image]